# Echo text including double quotes in PHP

Tags: php, double, echo, double-quotes

I have a $_GET[q] from the URL. I am trying to ECHO the search term back into the search box. Sometimes people might submit queries encapsulated in quotes and in these cases the ECHO interprets the search term

```
ECHO $_GET[q];
```

as:

```
ECHO ""search term"";
```

and as a result I get a blank search box. Search queries with a single quote, like: Peter's house, work fine.

When I use:

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET[q])
```

I only get a backslash in the search box.

How could I populate the search box with a search term encapsulated in double quotes?

Comment: `echo "text including double quotes";` -  Just kidding, use the single quotes `echo "'search term'"`;

Comment: as a note, it's very much preferred all round to use lowercase. SHOUTING COMMANDS ARE FRIENDLY TO READ

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix echo "'search term'" would result in 'search term'. What I need is "search term" , like when a user uses a boolean search using + - " etc...

Comment: The rest of this is too vague I would need to see more code, like the HTML for the search form.  And any SQL etc.  this doesn't happen.  `interprets the search term as .. ECHO ""search term"";`  -  then use `echo '"search term"';`  ()>==<{>===========>   That is my mighty bug smiting sword.... \\(o.0)/

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix The variable q is from the URL and I am just trying to echo it out even it it says /index.php?q="test" I would like to quotes appear. Simple as that but not as simple to do.

Comment: That makes a Huge difference.  The URL is badly formatted no telling what the server got.  Quotes should be `%22` in the URL.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix If I did echo '"search term"'; I would get: $_GET[q] as an output.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix - you are right, it should be encoded as %27 and it is not happening. I will look into it. This will be a good starrt for me.

Comment: I should have realized that sooner, but when you did the URL example, I was like - wait a minute - lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use:

```
echo str_replace('"','',$_GET[q]);
```

This will of course remove all double quotes, so if they may be valid somewhere in the search term then better might be:

```
echo str_replace('"','&quot;',$_GET[q]);
```

Haven't tested this but this might also work:

```
echo html_entity_decode(htmlentities($_GET[q))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [addslashes](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)

like this:

```php
$t = 'peter "pan"';
echo addslashes($t);  // outputs: peter \"pan\"
```

Comment: Your solution would work with a plain text but not with a variable.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try:**

```
$str = "Hello World!";
echo $str . "<br>";
echo chop($str,"");
```

**Ouptput:**

```
Hello World
```

**Explanation:**
  The `chop()` function, helps you chop off the quotes anyone might add to string.
  You can manipulate as appropriate for your code.

Comment: Hi. When the user uses double quotes in the search I want them to be echoed out as such. In your answer the double quotes are missing from around Hello world if the user typed: "Hello world"

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = preg_replace( '["|\']','',  $_REQUEST['q'] );

echo( $str ); //no double, no single quotes, faster than str_replace when you have to make more than 1 call to str_replace
```

or...

```
$str = str_replace( '"','',  $_REQUEST['q'] ); //no double quotes, faster than preg_replace when you only make one call to str_replace

echo( $str ); //no double quotes
```

Comment: Hi, this would remove the double quotes, but I do want them to be echoed out.